# Passing test if at least 3 of 5 executions were successful

Tags: java, testng

We have unstable test environment and some tests are occasionally failing due to environmental problems.

I would like each test to be executed maximally 5 times and be considered as successful if at least 3 of 5 those executions were successful.

How can I achieve that with TestNG?

Comment: I would *not* recommend this, and instead fix the environmental problems. Disable the tests if you must temporarily, but this seems a dangerous road to follow.

Comment: How will you distinguish between a failure due to environmental problems and a failure due to a software bug?  A software bug can still succeed 3 out of 5 times.  If your code is failing for any reason, you don't want to pass the unit test.

Comment: Would you be happy if production failed 2 out of 5 times. Note: you can get lucky and even if it fails most of the time, it might happen to pass 3 of 5 times.

Comment: Dont gamble with Production environment as @PeterLawrey said, not a sign of a good coder

Comment: It's bad enough when you are running 1000 passing tests and you still are likely to get failures in production.

Comment: My suggestion: either rewrite or throw away those tests. If they are not providing value, they sure still incure costs.

Comment: There is a successPercentage parameter on the Test annotation you can use on the method. Requires an integer.

Comment: @C.B. We follow mitigation strategy implemented by Google: "We have several mitigation strategies for flaky tests during presubmit testing, including the ability to re-run only failing tests, and an option to re-run tests automatically when they fail. We even have a way to denote a test as flaky - causing it to report a failure only if it fails 3 times in a row." : https://testing.googleblog.com/2016/05/flaky-tests-at-google-and-how-we.html. Unfortunately, fixing the environment is beyond our control.

Comment: One more thing. I am talking about end-to-end tests not unit tests. The latter are isolated from environmental problems.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has functionality to handle such cases. It's `IRetryAnalyzer` interface. You can easily find examples of it's implementation.

Before start using it you have to understand clearly that you have no other options except this one. Speak with stakeholders, try to find ways to stabilize your environment. While number of such test cases will grow you will go deeper into the regression death loop, just spending all the day on failures analysis.